# Is "further" really used as synonym of "farther"?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

The OALD, for the meaning of *further* says:

> (comparative of far) (especially BrE) at or to a greater distance **SYN** farther

Is *further* really used as synonym of *farther*?
As far as I recall, there is a slightly different meaning between those words. I don't recall  that exactly, but I think I was taught that *further* is used *figuratively*, such as in "I cannot go any further into this discussion."

Comment: That's the distinction I draw in my own use; but I don't think the distinction is observed widely enough to say it's **the** distinction.

Comment: That is what I was taught as well. "Farther" should always be used for literal distance, while "further" is used for everything else. English being what it is, the line is blurred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few relevant pronouncements culled from [dailywritingtips.com](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/farther-further-whats-the-difference/)...

> The *OED* says
>    In standard English the form farther is usually preferred where the word is intended to be the comparative of far, while further is used where the notion of far is altogether absent.
>   It concedes, however, that “there is a large intermediate class of instances in which the choice between the two forms is arbitrary.”
>
> According to the *Online Etymology Dictionary*
>    There is no historical basis for the notion that farther is of physical distance and further of degree or quality.
>
> In 1926 H.W. Fowler wrote in *A Dictionary of Modern English Usage*
>    The fact is surely that hardly anyone uses the two words for different occasions; most people prefer one or the other for all purposes, and the preference of the majority is for further.

---

As these NGrams for [advanced further/farther](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=advanced%20further,advanced%20farther&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) and [further/farther advanced](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=further%20advanced,farther%20advanced&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=) show, there's no significant preference based on word position, or UK/US usage. What stands out is *further* is always more common.

Thus, even if some people (i.e. [Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/further-versus-farther.aspx)) do distinguish either the precise meanings, or the contexts in which they use each form, this is effectively irrelevant, since most of us *don't*. It's just pedantry.

---

But there are contexts where *farther* is never used. In "fixed expressions" such as [further education](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Further_education) (BrE for AmE [continuing education](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuing_education)), and as the verb [to further](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/further_4) *(to develop or make progress in something)*.

Comment: _most people prefer one or the other for all purposes_ I find this true, at least for myself. I had read some prescriptive opinion that _farther_ should be used for physical distance, but I think I find myself using _further_ almost, if not entirely, exclusively.

Comment: @TecBrat: ***Furthermore***, I should point out that although [***farthermost*** does actually occur](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=furthermost%2Cfarthermost&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfurthermost%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfarthermost%3B%2Cc0), the corresponding [***farthermore*** is virtually unknown](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=furthermore%2Cfarthermore&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfurthermore%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfarthermore%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 5):

Pam Peters, who is often criticized by EL&U  community, says that "The idea that farther and further work in different realms is not sustainable. [...] both forms are now freely applied to 'spatial, temporal or metaphorical distance'."

Pam Peters derive her conclusions from British National Corpus and American English from the Cambridge International Corpus.

Comment: +1 It makes a change to see a context where I can wholeheartedly agree with Ms Peters! Actually, my only problem with her pronouncements is that sometimes they're a bit too "prescriptive" for my taste, but obviously that doesn't apply here!

Answer (score -1):

"Farther" seems to be one of the many differences of American English. It's not really used in England and the rest of the UK. I have only heard it used by Americans, on television programmes. It is explained further in these links http://english-usage-mcallister.blogspot.co.uk/2006/06/farther-or-further.html and 
http://random-idea-english.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/q-further-or-farther-british.html

It sounds weird from an English perspective.

Comment: I don't agree with this at all. My own answer includes links to NGrams which show no significant difference between US/UK preferences. All I see is that *further* has always been the dominant form, and that preference has probably increased slightly over the past century.

Comment: FF, I have only heard "farther" used by Americans. Not even once have I heard it used by British people.

Comment: [Great Expectations, Volume 1, Chapter 3](http://texts.crossref-it.info/text/great-expectations/volume-1-chapter-3): *"I wonder you shouldn't have been sure of that," I returned, "for we heard it up at home, and that's **farther** away, and we were shut in besides."* I know that's only one example - but like I said before, NGrams give the big picture more reliably.

Comment: Yes, it's only one and from how long ago? It's not in general use in the current era.

Comment: Okay, well, I'll grant that Americans favour *farther away* over *further away* by [about 3:2](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=further+away%2Cfarther+away&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=), whereas for Brits it's more like [1:3 in the opposite direction](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=further+away%2Cfarther+away&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=), so I'll cancel that downvote. But note from that second link that before the 1960s (i.e. - back when I learnt English! :) even Brits favoured *farther* for that one.