# What does "the boat sheered off to beach further up the coast" mean?

Tags: meaning

I just have no ideas of what "further up the coast" means.

I know every word of the sentence but it's still all Greek to me.

Comment: You could rewrite it like this:  The boat turned away from the rest of the group in order to go up to to the shore some distance more along the coastline.

Comment: Technically, it should be “... **farther** up the coast.”

Comment: TJY - I'm not sure what you mean by "technically;" many dictionaries acknowledge that _farther_ can be used in place of _further_, although it's apparently a contentious issue among etymological experts. See the very interesting Usage Note [here](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry?id=F0043200).

Comment: J.R., you're right. *Farther* is not really used here in England and the rest of the UK.

Comment: @Tristan I've always just assumed y'all don't use "farther" because it would sound like "father" in y'all's non-rhotic accents.

Comment: @J.R. I did find that usage note interesting. This was not a rule I learned with any caveat or newness disclaimer. I will henceforth flag this preference as not only pedantic but also not at all universal.

Comment: @J.R. FWIW, ELU [agrees with me](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/when-should-farther-and-further-be-used) even if ELL [doesn't](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5522/is-further-really-used-as-synonym-of-farther). I'd rather align myself here, among the free.

Comment: Tyler, that could be part of the reason but, it is mainly because the word *further* is already in use so, saying *farther* is just unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

[image]

Point A is a point on the coast. Point B is a point "further up the coast".

Note: The word *point* here refers to "a particular spot, place, or position in an area or on a map" (NOAD Def. 3) not "a narrow piece of land jutting out into a lake or ocean" (NOAD Def. 7) Referring to the latter definition, we could say that Point B is *quite near the point*.