# "Further" in terms of destination point

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-request

Here is the situation, two men in the train, one asks another if the current station is the one he needs. It's not the one. The first man wants to say that the station the second guy needs is  gonna be one of next stations without explicitly telling which one exactly.

Can he say "Your station is further", if not, what's the proper way of saying that?

Comment: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5522/is-further-really-used-as-synonym-of-farther

Comment: "Your station is a **bit further** *(along)*, maybe 3 or 4 more stops." **Bit further** is a little further, only using **further** could be anywhere between here and the north Pole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option is fine. Also acceptable:

> Your station is down the line

or

> Your station is farther down the line

or even

> Your station is in a few more stops

Answer (score 0):

"Your station is further" is not to my ear at all idiomatic. I'd be wondering "further *what*?"

I would use either "further on" or "further along" if I absolutely had to use the word "further", but I'd much more likely say something like

> No, but it's coming up soon.

or

> No, not for a while.

I would not reply in the negative without using the word "no" first, especially in a loud environment like a train.

Answer (score 0):

While "your station is further down the line" is common and most people won't have any problem with it, it is technically wrong.

Further is used for metaphorical or figurative expressions.  For example, do you understand the math problem now, or should I explain further?

Farther is used for physical distances.  An easy way to remember the difference is that "farther" contains "far" as in a far away place.